# Laravel left join AS

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

So I'm trying to get a Laravel Eloquent query to work. Here's the scenario:

1) I have one table called `c5_wall_route_taxonomies` That looks like the following:

```
---------------------------------------------
| ID   |  TYPE       |   CREATED_ON         |
---------------------------------------------
| 2    | 'country'   |  2014-08-12 12:12:12 |
---------------------------------------------
```

Where ID is an auto-incrementing integer, TYPE is an enum, and CREATED_ON is a pretty standard timestamp.

2) I have another table called `c5_wall_route_taxonomy_options` that looks like the following:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| ID   |  WALL_ROUTE_TAXONOMY_ID   |  META_KEY   | META_VALUE   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1    | 2                         | 'label'     | 'Malaysia'   |
| 2    | 2                         | 'code'      | 'MY'         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I'm trying to get the fields from the `c5_wall_route_taxonomy` table along with an extra 'country_label' field.

```
$result = DB::table('wall_route_taxonomies')
            ->join('wall_route_taxonomy_options as country', function($join) {
                $join->on('wall_route_taxonomies.id', '=', 'country.wall_route_taxonomy_id')
                     ->where('country.meta_key', '=', 'label');
            })->get();
```

Note that my table prefix is `c5_`.

Laravel tells me that it's unable to find `c5_country.wall_route_taxonomy_id`.

Now in this scenario, I could always just opt not to use the alias, and just use `wall_route_taxonomy_options.wall_route_taxonomy_id` instead, but what if I wanted to get both the label and the code from the options table as individual fields in my output?

Surely there's a way to implement this in Laravel?

Comment: Have you tried it before using the table alias? Does it find it then?

Comment: Also how come you are not choosing to use relationships? It makes this a whole lot cleaner in my opinion

Comment: @bencarter78 -> (re using it before alias) Haven't tried that, will give it a go ASAP.

On the relationships side, `c5_wall_route_taxonomy_options` is not tied to a Eloquent model (which is why I'm using `DB::` as opposed to `WallRouteTaxonomy::`.

I am, of course, assuming that relationships can only be established between 2 Eloquent models, and not tables themselves?

Comment: have you tried using `as c5_country` in your join statement